# How do you find the velocity and acceleration of a particle at $t$ minutes given by $s(t)=25t - \ln t~\text{cm}$?

Tags: calculus

The particle is moving in a straight line with a position at $t$ minutes given by $s(t)=25t-\ln t~\text{cm}$.

How do I find the acceleration and velocity?

I've assumed to find the velocity that I differentiate $s(t)$ which comes to

$v(t)=s'(t)=24$.

This doesn't look correct to me and was wondering where I went wrong?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't differentiate it properly.  $s'(t)=25-\frac 1t$ cm/min.  Now differentiate it again for the acceleration.